# How can i 'get' the number i have entered into the label widget into a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

I I have 2 functions and the second function should run after the button in the first one has been clicked. This works fine, however I need the number that has been entered to go into a variable and so far the .get() function is not working and im not sure what to do.

I have looked at a lot of different examples, including login and sign up gui's however none of them have been able to help.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box


def enter_rle_1():

    enter_rle = Tk() #do not remove
    enter_rle.title('Enter RLE') #do not remove

    frame = Frame(enter_rle) #do not remove

    label_linecount = Label(enter_rle,text = 'Linecount:')
    label_linecount.pack(padx=15,pady= 5)

    linecount = Entry(enter_rle,bd =5)
    linecount.pack(padx=15, pady=5)


    ok_button = Button(enter_rle, text="Next", command = linecount_button_clicked)
    ok_button.pack(side = RIGHT , padx =5)


    frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 19)
    enter_rle.mainloop()


def linecount_button_clicked():
     Linecount = linecount.get()

     if int(Linecount) < 3:
            tm.showinfo("Error", "Enter a number over 3")
     elif int(Linecount) > 1000000000:
            tm.showinfo("Error", "Enter a number under 1,000,000,000")
     else:
            print("fdsfd")

enter_rle_1()
```

I expect there to be a popup telling me the number is too big or too small, depending on wether the number is or not, and if it is a good number, i just have it set as a print as some code to test to see if it works before i move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a String variable for the Entry widget (Make sure it is global defined):

```
global linecount_STR
linecount_STR = StringVar()
linecount_STR.set('Enter value here')
linecount = Entry(enter_rle,bd =5,textvariable=linecount_STR)
linecount.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
```

The number entered there can then be read with `int(linecount_STR.get())`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest an OO approach, look this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.vcmd = (self.register(self.validate), '%d', '%P', '%S')

        self.linecount = tk.IntVar()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Label(f, text = "Linecount").pack()
        self.txTest = ttk.Entry(f,
                                validate='key',
                                validatecommand=self.vcmd,
                                textvariable=self.linecount).pack()

        w = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Button(w, text="Next", command=self.on_callback).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


    def on_callback(self,):

        #print ("self.text = {}".format(self.linecount.get()))

        x = self.linecount.get()

        if x < 3:
            msg = "Enter a number over 3"
        elif x > 1000000000:
            msg = "Enter a number under 1,000,000,000"
        else:
            msg = "You ahve enter {0}".format(x)

        messagebox.showinfo(self.parent.title(), msg, parent=self)            


    def on_close(self):
        self.parent.on_exit()


    def validate(self, action, value, text,):
        # action=1 -> insert
        if action == '1':
            if text in '0123456789':
                try:
                    int(value)
                    return True
                except ValueError:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True        

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_title()
        self.set_style()

        frame = Main(self,)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")

    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('Enter RLE')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

notice this line at the begin....

self.linecount = tk.IntVar()# declare an integer variable

self.vcmd = (self.register(self.validate), '%d', '%P', '%S')#register a function to allow only integer in your text widget.

Comment: the code in this confused me a bit but i got the general idea of it so thank you, however im going to use the other apporach as it is easier for me to do, but thanks anyway :)